# setting the value in json array based on checking some condition

Tags: java, java-8

I have this method `pay.getPaymentDetails()` of which return type is string and it return the below string

```json
[
    {
        "mcTtid": 201657083281,
        "cardLast4Digits": "0887",
        "paymentType": "CREDIT CARD",
        "originalPaymentCategory": {
            "code": "Q",
            "name": "CREDIT CARD"
        }
    },
    {
        "veTtid": 21656148003,
        "cardLast4Digits": "4777",
        "paymentType": "GIFT CARD",
        "originalPaymentCategory": {
            "code": "Q",
            "name": "GIFT CARD"
        }
    },
    {
        "mcTtid": 201625819,
        "cardLast4Digits": "8388",
        "paymentType": "GIFT CARD",
        "originalPaymentCategory": {
            "code": "w",
            "name": "GIFT CARD"
        }
    }
]
```

Now with the below code I have extracted the value of attribute paymentType

```java
String paymentTypeValue = null;
try {
    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(FormatUtil.gcpBlobAsString(pay.getPaymentDetails()));
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
        paymentTypeValue = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("paymentType");
    }
}
catch (JSONException e) {
    logger.error("Json exception-->" + e.getMessage());
    throw new JsonException(e);
}
```

Now mine query is that I need to check that if the value attribute paymentType is GIFT CARD then I need to set it to CREDIT CARD so please advise how can I set that back that

```java
if (paymentTypeValue.equalsIgnoreCase("GIFT CARD")) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.put(fieldName, newValue)` method. It replaces an already existing field or adds it.

Here is an example:

```java
String paymentTypeValue = null;
try {
    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(FormatUtil.gcpBlobAsString(pay.getPaymentDetails()));
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject currentObject = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
        paymentTypeValue = currentObject.getString("paymentType");
        
        if (paymentTypeValue.equalsIgnoreCase("GIFT CARD")) {
            currentObject.put("paymentType", "CREDIT CARD"); // <------------- This does what you need
        }
    }
    
    // Get your JSON array and turn it into a string or whatever you need
}
catch (JSONException e) {
    logger.error("Json exception-->" + e.getMessage());
    throw new JsonException(e);
}
```